# Scale coordinates got on a device

Tags: java, android, coordinates, scale, draw

I'm developing an Android app which lets the user draws and then checks if it has drawn inside a shape or not. The coordinates of the shape are retrieved by a .txt created before. Now, I created it on a Google Pixel C, so when the user draws the algorithm I made do not have any problem. I tried the app on a Galaxy Tab, which has a screen resolution of 1920 x 1200 and the shape its obviously in a different position. I made this method which converts the coordinates but it doesn't work:

```
public void loadShapePoints () {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    Display display = getWindowManager(). getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display. getSize(size);
    int width = size. x;
    int height = size. y;
    float tmp = 0;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(protocol+cornice)));
        String mLine;
        for (int elem=0; (mLine = reader.readLine()) != null; elem++) {
            mLine = mLine.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            if (elem%2==0) {
                tmp = Float.parseFloat(mLine);
            } else {
                float x = Float.valueOf(tmp)*(width/(float)2560);
                float y = Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(mLine))*(height/(float)1704);
                Pair p1 = new Pair(x, y);
                points.add(p1);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    drawView.setShape(points);
}
```

I'm reading the file on this way because it is structured as well:
line 1: x1
line 2: y1
line 3: x2...
I used 2560x1740 in the conversion because it is the resolution of the Google Pixel C which I used on the emulator to develop the app. 
I noticed that the only way to make it works on the Galaxy Tab A is to put 2600x2200 as coordinates (I don't know why), but obviously if I put this value it will not works as soon as I get back on the Pixel C. How can I convert them? Can the problem is that the drawing area is divided into 3 part which gets resized on different screen resolutions? This is the xml of the area:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FCFCFC"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
tools:context=".PaintingActivity" >

<!-- Top Buttons -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/brush"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/brush" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/erase_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/erase"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eraser" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/undo_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Undo"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/undo" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Custom View -->

<com.example.sample.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />

<!-- Menu in basso -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Top Row -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toprow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/form_intro"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittitle"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Row -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:text="Avanti"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks like and its structure:
[image]

EDIT: the problem is that if I draw this segment on the Pixel C I get these coordinates:

> 1540.9375,
>   513.01074

If I do it on the Galaxy Tab A I get these:

> 1158.0,
>   279.0

[image]

Comment: can you provide the desired output and the output with the faults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved modifying the method as well:

```
public void loadShapePoints () {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    float height = drawView.getCanvasHeight();
    float width = drawView.getCanvasWidth();
    float tmp = 0;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(protocol+cornice)));
        String mLine;
        for (int elem=0; (mLine = reader.readLine()) != null; elem++) {
            mLine = mLine.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            if (elem%2==0) {
                tmp = Float.parseFloat(mLine);
            } else {
                float x = (width/2540)*(Float.valueOf(tmp));
                float y = (height/1109)*(Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(mLine)));
                Pair p1 = new Pair(x, y);
                points.add(p1);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    drawView.setShape(points);
}
```

The problem was that the drawing area was getting reduced on each device, so, since it has a different size than the screen, I had to manually calculate it and divide per the Google Pixel C drawing area size (2540x1109).